Accessing an Ubuntu 24.04 machine via rdp port selection
So I'm running a new Ubuntu 24.04 machine at work and we have this system for using RDP to get into windows machines. The system they have setup gives me no ability to control the port at which RDP connection takes place and is autoset to 3389 as default.
I setup Desktop sharing via the Gnome system settings and on 24.04 it's set to 3390 and I can't change it to 3389. How do I change this port on my Ubuntu machine as I can't change anything on the departments RDP system?
P.S. I saw other users ask similar questions but all their solutions involved modifying it on the RDP client side which I can't change.

Disable the Remote Desktop in gnome settings. Desktop sharing should go back to port 3389.

Thank you! I tested it and I was able to remote in when on the same network with that port specified. I will test the external access system when I can.

Please accept the answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

Desktop Sharing vs Remote Login
Ubuntu 24.04 has two options for remote desktop access.

Desktop Sharing is for sharing the desktop of the local user with someone remotely located. Optionally the remote person may be given control of the desktop. One such use of this feature is, you may leave your work computer in the logged in state, and go home. Then you can remotely connect to your work computer and continue to work from home.
Remote Login allows remotely logging into the work computer when no one is locally logged in.

Unlike RDP in Windows, these two are separate features in Ubuntu and cannot be combined into one option. Both the options can be turned on at the same time. However, since they both use the same RDP protocol, the port used by Desktop Sharing is changed to 3390 when the Remote Login option is also active.
Use port 3389 for Desktop Sharing
Warning: This solution turns off the Remote Login option. That means if you log out of the work computer or if it is restarted when you are away, you will not be able to access the computer remotely.

Open the settings app and go to the System tab on the left panel
 Click on the Remote Desktop on the right panel.
You will see the Desktop Sharing page. Click on the Remote Login tab on the top of the page.
Unlock the choices by clicking on the unlock button on the top right corner. and disable Remote Login.

Return to the Desktop Sharing Tab and check if the port is 3389. If not, you may have to disable and enable Desktop Sharing to make the port 3389.
Hope this helps

Using Remote Desktop Connection client on Windows, you can specify the port after a colon.
Computer: 192.168.1.100:3390
In the example above, 192.168.1.100 is the address of the computer you want to connect to (replace with the IP address of your computer). 3390 is the port.
